# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes)...in mysqli.php on line 483

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla1.5, fatal-error

I am trying to upgrade my website joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 using jUpgrade. but I am encountering this problem since a long time. jUpgrade component starts upgrading, downloads and exctracts the new joomla but while migrating the categories OR contents, it stucks and gives this error:

---

==========
[undefined] [undefined]

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in /home/daneshna/public_html/up/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysqli.php on line 483

---

I tried allocating more memory size in php.ini file in the server to even 1028M (128M was the default), but this problem persists and I cant get through with it. Tried everything I could find online, but its still there.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

(p.s. my website is www.daneshnamah.com, a persian educational website run from Afghanistan since almost 4 years perfectly with over 6000 articles in it and over 19M visitors so far, bcz of security reasons now I wanna upgrade it to 2.5)

Thank You

- Ebtihaj

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something (you added recently?) is eating up massive amounts of memory.
Things like that happen often with PHP which is why it shouldn't be used for more than Hypertext.

Did you restart your webserver after changing the php.ini?

What you can do to identify the hungry parts of your website is use [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to see where the memory is eaten up.

If you recently added code/plugins, you can simply remove half of your new additions, see if it happens again, if it does, comment out half of that, etc, and keep doing this until you found the culprit.